Is there any way to fix host port while attaching intellij debugger and docker compose?
I am using IntelliJ Ultimate to develop Spring Boot application. I found this link and followed everything to integrate Intellij debugger and Docker container(created via docker-compose).
I ended up given hands on finally and this works well. However, there is a problem. Whenever I execute "run" or "debug" command via Intellij, docker picks the random number of host machine and forward to application's port.
I want to fix the "port number of host machine".
I tried to modify "docker-compose.yml" as below.
# ...
services:
  java:
    platform: linux/x86_64
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      - test
# ...

But, this never works. Is there any solution for this or any recommendation for constructing dev environment?

I wouldn't force Docker into this setup.  Just install a JVM on your host system with your IDE.
